# listview, onItemClickListener doesn't work

Tags: android

I have search a lot, my item in the listView is a linearlayout, and I have already add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`, but it doesn't work.

I have also see that ,someone say override `getView()` in adapter, and add onCLickListener to the view, I don't know it will work or not on earth,but why onItemClickListener can not work.

And setOnItemSelectedListener works well .why?! can not get a clue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/item_style"
android:focusable="true"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_item_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    />
<TextView android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:id="@+id/dialog_item_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:padding="5dp"       
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"  
    /> 

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_item_sel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    />
```

```
 private class FileListView extends ListView{
    private List<Map<String, Object>> tempShowList ;
    public FileListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setSelector(R.drawable.item_unfocus);
        this.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        this.setClickable(true);
        this.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                       Log.e("on item click","here");
                     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: did you try beforeDescendants?

Comment: you say android:descendantFocusability= beforeDescendants? or not setting this? I have tried not setting anthing in vain. @Yashwanth Kumar

Comment: I tried beforeDescendants.in vain..what on earth it gets problems!!

Comment: Where's the code where you're setting the listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already know how to solve this problem. As I have write the adapter myself.And in the getView() method in adapter. I set the view clickable. which makes this problem. cause that the click action will be first handled by the child view ,when it doesn't handle this action, its parent will handle it later.